# Error Unless Declared Static

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a class,any member in it that I don't declare static will have this error if I reference it inside the class:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to brush up your knowledge of static vs. non-static class members: [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: Show us the code for the the member and method that cause the error, please.

Comment: The first thing you've done wrong is asking this type of question without including the exact source code that you've tried to compile. There's nothing wrong with the language, but it's much easier to explain if we had your code in front of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get that error if you are accessing a *instance* method from a *static* context. For example

```
public class Dog
{
  public void Speak(){ Console.WriteLine( "Bark" ); }

  public static void KickDog(){ 
    Speak(); // <- Error here
  }
}
```

Instead you need to create an instance of the class

```
public static void KickDog()
{
  new Dog().Speak();
}
```

However, a mix-up like this might suggest a misunderstanding of C# semantics and I'd recommend picking up any one of the intro to C# books on Amazon to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "reference it inside the class", I assume you mean referencing the non-static member from a member that *is* static. Code such as this will produce this error:

```
class Broken
{
    static void Foo()
    {
        Bar();
    }

    void Bar()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The context of a static member is the class itself, not instances (objects) of the class. You can reference a static member of a class without an object instance at all.

Instance members (instance is the opposite of static in this case) are associated with object instances of a class. This implies they can reference object-specific data (i.e non-static fields) as well as other instance members. For this reason, to reference an instance member, you must have an object reference.

If a static member references an instance member, where is the object that the instance member will reference? There isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

main() starts in a [static context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx). To access non-static fields you need to create an instance of the class.